# Why am I getting this Laravel 4 error: "User must implement Remindable interface"

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to implement a user Auth (reset email function) using MySQL and i keep getting this error `User must implement Remindable interface.` and I know that `User` is implementing `RemindableInterface` because I am using the Auth system that comes with Laravel 4.

And the correct database credentials was entered in the database config file. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Here is the code:

### config/auth.php

```
return array(

  /*
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Default Authentication Driver
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |
  | This option controls the authentication driver that will be utilized.
  | This drivers manages the retrieval and authentication of the users
  | attempting to get access to protected areas of your application.
  |
  | Supported: "database", "eloquent"
  |
  */

  'driver' => 'database',

  /*
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Authentication Model
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |
  | When using the "Eloquent" authentication driver, we need to know which
  | Eloquent model should be used to retrieve your users. Of course, it
  | is often just the "User" model but you may use whatever you like.
  |
  */

  'model' => 'User',

  /*
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Authentication Table
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |
  | When using the "Database" authentication driver, we need to know which
  | table should be used to retrieve your users. We have chosen a basic
  | default value but you may easily change it to any table you like.
  |
  */

  'table' => 'users',

  /*
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Password Reminder Settings
  |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |
  | Here you may set the settings for password reminders, including a view
  | that should be used as your password reminder e-mail. You will also
  | be able to set the name of the table that holds the reset tokens.
  |
  | The "expire" time is the number of minutes that the reminder should be
  | considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
  | they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
  |
  */

  'reminder' => array(

    'email' => 'emails.auth.reminder',

    'table' => 'password_reminders',

    'expire' => 60

  )

);
```

### models/User.php

```
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;
class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface
{

  /**
   * The database table used by the model.
   *
   * @var string
   */
  protected $table = 'users';

  /**
   * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
   *
   * @var array
   */
  protected $hidden = array('password');

  /**
   * Get the unique identifier for the user.
   *
   * @return mixed
   */
  public function getAuthIdentifier()
  {
    return $this->getKey();
  }

  /**
   * Get the password for the user.
   *
   * @return string
   */
  public function getAuthPassword()
  {
    return $this->password;
  }

  /**
   * Get the e-mail address where password reminders are sent.
   *
   * @return string
   */
  public function getReminderEmail()
  {
    return $this->email;
  }

}
```

Comment: Did you try `'driver' => 'database',` to `'driver' => 'eloquent',` on `config/auth.php`? (You're extending `Eloquent`) or maybe add `protected $key = 'userid';` or `protected $primaryKey = 'userid';` to `model/User.php`

Comment: thanks for your reply and i will try your suggestions. I am using MySQL not Eloquent and all the examples that i saw extends eloquent so i don't know which class to extend if not Eloquent on User.php

Comment: I tried your suggestions, but still nothing. what i am trying to implement is the password reset function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `'driver' => 'database'` you don't need to specify any model either worrying about that because the `Auth` will work with the table directly using query builder. I recommend you to use `eloquent` because through the model you can get more functionalities such as reminders, relationship access, etc.

Comment: Ok i guess i had the wrong understanding about eloquent vs the database driver. its working now thank you for your answer. i really appreciate it.